# Has phone normalization logic changed recently (November'15)?

Tags: contact, search

The thing is that previously we were able to find contact, for instance, via `searchAndScreenPop`, with phone number slightly different from one that is actually used in search query. For example, instead of `+02247000` it could have been `+0 (224)70 0-0 x22` - salesforce just used to strip away all irrelevant characters (including x22 postfix).

It looks like it is not a case anymore.

The question is - where I can find information about the stripping logic used in `searchAndScreenPop`

Answer (score 1):

We've recently experienced exactly the same issue. This change seems to have sneaked by under the radar. All we've found are these release notes:

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_search_tokenization_punctuation.htm?edition=&impact=

Notice how at the end it says:

> These improvements are available on a rolling basis starting with the
>   Summer ’15 release and before the Spring ’16 release.

We have seen this 'creeping up' in more and more of our customers. My guess is that it's being deployed onto different instances gradually.

**Workaround**

Our workaround is to strip the leading plus:

Instead of looking for +02247000, just search for 02247000

This seems to happen in all SOSL queries (and I suspect that searchAndScreenPop is just a nice javascript wrapper around SOSL).

You can test this by running a SOSL query in anonymous window:

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND '+02247000' IN Phone FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, Name)];
System.Debug (searchList);
```

This will not return any results, whereas this: (notice the stripped plus)

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND '02247000' IN Phone FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, Name)];
System.Debug (searchList);
```

Will return your contact.

You can also verify this by typing in the Salesforce search box.

We want to raise a case with Salesforce. Please update this question if you find any extra information.